# Problema al intentar acceder a un dato en una relación en laravel

Tags: laravel-8

estoy trabajando en un sistema en laravel y resulta que intentar acceder a un atributo mediante la relación en la vista me dice esto

""Attempt to read property "nombre" on null""

me paso anteriormente con con otra relación y mi solución fue eliminar las migraciones que había creado y volverlas a crear y se solucionó el problema pero esta vez no e podido solucionarlo no se que pueda hacer tengo otras relaciones pero esta es la única relación con la que e tenido más problemas, espero y me puedan ayudar.